# Original 1925 paper by Einstein on Bose-Einstein Condensation?

Tags: specific-reference, bose-einstein-condensate

Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve the original 1925 paper by Einstein on Bose-Einstein Condensation? Possibly a translation into english, but german would be fine if no translation is available. I have managed to find a translation of *Quantentheorie des einatomigen idealen Gases* (Quantum Theory of a Monoatomic Ideal Gas) from 1924 where it is referenced as *Sitzungsberichte der Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften, Berlin, Physikalisch-mathematische Klasse, 1925, p. 3–14*, but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I found the following translation [Quantum Theory of the Ideal Monoatomic Gas (1925)](http://wavewatching.net/lost-papers/quantum-theory-of-ideal-monoatomic-gases-final-draft/).  The first paper (1924) can be found in translation here [Quantum Theory of a Monoatomic Ideal Gas (1924)](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~amendola/otherstuff/einstein-paper-v2.pdf).

Comment: @StephenG That should be an answer

Comment: @DavidZ  Done as per suggestion.  I figured this was a link-only answer so I commented but I guess it's an exception.

Comment: @StephenG I see where you're going with that, but this type of question (i.e.
 [tag:specific-reference] that is asking to track down a hard-to-find paper) is completely answered by the link itself. So the usual rule that link-only answers are bad doesn't apply. (One could argue that makes them bad questions, but the community seems to think they're okay, and they are fairly rare anyway.)

Comment: (cont.) Anyway, in general when you have a link that answers a question, the better way to proceed is post an answer with the link and with enough extra text so that a reader doesn't _have_ to click the link. Comments aren't really supposed to be used as "mini-answers" like this. (Or as full answers, or as answers of any kind.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following translations :

- [Quantum Theory of the Ideal Monoatomic Gas (1925)](http://wavewatching.net/lost-papers/quantum-theory-of-ideal-monoatomic-gases-final-draft/).
- The first paper (1924) can be found in translation here [Quantum Theory of a Monoatomic Ideal Gas](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~amendola/otherstuff/einstein-paper-v2.pdf).

As I don't understand German I can't speak to the accuracy of the translations, but they do seem to have been done by someone who understands physics.

Comment: And a good research librarian can get copies of the originals. Not everything is online.

Comment: @StephenG in the first link, in the very first paragraph, it's written `Mr. D. Bose`, but it should have been `Mr. S. Bose` instead (Satyendranath Bose). Can you comment on this? Is that translation error?

Comment: (A few years late) The original German version was Hrn. D. Bose (see my answer). I believe the D. in this case stands for *Doktor*, so mr. doctor Bose.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the original german [A Scanned version is provided by the university of Münster](https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_ap/demokritov/mbecfornonphysicists/einstein_1924_1925.pdf)